# Difference between type and similarity type

Tags: reference-request, logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

In usual terminology, is there a difference between the **type** and **similarity type**? Is there a general consensus for the definition of the two terms?

Please suggest to me books where I can study these themes. I have to solve problems in which I need to say if a given affirmation is demonstrable or not, and if it is, then demonstrate that. On the other hand, I need to give the necessary similarity type to traduce a formula into first order language. I need to say if a given formula is or not universally valid. Can you recommend to me some references for approaching this particular problem?

Comment: The word type has many meanings in logic. In addition to "similarity type", which is a synonym for signature, and its meaning in type theory, it has a [standard meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_%28model_theory%29) in model theory.

Answer (score 0):

In usual terminology, we talk of a **type** **similarity type** as a synonym for **signature**. Recall that given a signature $\Sigma$ we can build a language $L(\Sigma)$ which alphabet usually consists of the predicate (if any), function (if any) and constant symbols (if any) of $\Sigma$ added by the logical symbols and auxiliary symbols of $L$. For a reasonable explanation, see van Dalen *Logic and Structure* (pp.58-62).

Comment: so, type and similarity type are distinct things?

Comment: @BBentzen Are you suggesting that "signature" and "similarity type" mean different things, and that "type" means the same thing are "signature"? I've never heard this usage before.

Comment: Also, what is a homomorphism between two (or more) signatures? I agree that the notion of signature is connected to the notion of homomorphism (of structures!), since two structures must have the same signature to even make sense of the definition of homomorphism. But to write "they have the same 'type', i.e. there is a homomorphism between them" is a bit misleading, since it's possible for two structure to have the same signature despite there being no homomorphism between them.

Comment: Sure: (1) Take any two fields of different characteristic. (2) Take $\Sigma = \{P,Q\}$, where $P$ and $Q$ are unary predicates. Let $A$ be the structure with one element which satisfies $P$ but not $Q$, and let $B$ be the structure with one element which satisfies $Q$ but not $P$.